# Getting Google OAuth in iOS accepted by Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, app-store, appstore-approval

I have developed an iOS app that allows users to login via their Google Account using OAuth.

It was rejected by Apple for allegedly violating 11.13 of the App Store Review Guidelines:

`11.13 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected`

Upon asking for more information, Apple said:

`To clarify, your app has been rejected for including means for users to acquire new Google accounts. Linking customers to a page where users may sign up or register new accounts, and then use those accounts to purchase service/server space to be used within the app, is not appropriate and must be removed before resubmitting your app.`

Here's a screenshot of the infringing functionality:

[image: Link Email Account]

The Gmail iOS app has the same screen and I can't find any other app that connects to Google by OAuth so I'm at a loss on how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

**EDIT: Here's a screenshot of same offending screen in Gmail**

[image: Gmail sign in]

Comment: My Google account shows that Reeder on my iOS devices has an OAuth token if you're looking for an app as an example.

Comment: I'm not totally sure SO is the right place for app review questions, but have you tried filing an appeal in addition for asking for more information? That would be my first avenue if I was in your shoes.

Comment: I'm definitely appealing in Resolution Center but wanted to ask publicly if anyone had experienced this before.

Comment: @ipsim what happened? Did you find a solution or you changed something in your app?

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

Google has finally added a native library that performs in-app sign in. You can find it here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start

### Original Post

This has happened to several users and unfortunately Google are still "working" on a solution.

I would strongly recommend that anyone facing this issue please comment in the [official forum](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900). The more attention it gets the higher the chance something will be done about it. Here's what one of the employees at Google had to say:

> Hi all -- at Google, we aim to make our services available to as many
> users and developers as possible. We have heard a very small number of
> reports of problems of this type, but those app developers appear to
> have eventually gotten approval to launch by working through Apple’s
> standard process.
>
> Meantime, we're continuing to work on improved mechanisms for login. I
> do agree with Daniel that direct use of GTMOauth2ViewControllerTouch,
> or the equivalent UIWebView trickery, is not recommended.

Right now the solution I used was to remove Sign In from the Launch Screen and move it to the menu inside our app.

Answer (score 1):

Place a link mentioned below instead of SignUP button:

[https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fca%2F&ltmpl=default&hl=en](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/&ltmpl=default&hl=en)

This link should be open in iOS Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing happen to me, but for a different service (SmugMug). In my situation, I worked with SmugMug and they provided for me an OAuth authorization page that didn't have the sign up button.

Some months ago, [same thing with Dropbox](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57425736-37/apple-reportedly-working-with-dropbox-on-rejected-apps/). Dropbox also ended up providing a login page without a sign up button temporarily, but they got a little more cooperation with Apple.

Perhaps we can try to collectively get Google to provide the same. Even though we're iOS developers, Im' sure Google wants to support development of iOS apps that use their platform.

Have you tried contacting Google?

Comment: I have tried contacting Google but they're near impossible to get in touch with. The new Google+ iOS app uses a different OAuth login url without the "sign up" components. If I find the time, I may use a network sniffer to find that url and use it instead.

What I've done for now is intercept the HTML and remove the offending "sign up" components but that defeats the purpose of handling authentication without the app manipulating anything.

Comment: Maybe the google-oauth guys would be worth asking? http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/